# How to animate a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following issue:

In my game there's a button called Menu and its initial state is false, because it only shows up when the player presses ESC. However, when the player put the mouse over the button, I want it to increases its size, but it doesn't work. I'm using this conditions, the state Highlighted is to increase the button's size:

[image]

The thing is if I put its initial state as true, it works. Why?

How can I solve this?

Comment: In Java at least, while(false) {/*increase size*/} never executes because it is impossible for a false condition to be true. You say you get the desired results by setting the initial state to true, so what's wrong with that?

Comment: The problem is that I use ESC to pause the game and a menu screen shows up as well. When the player press the button Menu he goes back to the initial menu of the game. I wanna the button Menu to appear only if the player press ESC.

Comment: You say that you want the menu button to appear only when the player presses escape. In that case, how is it a problem that pressing the escape key causes the menu screen to show up?